# Why can my function change my array if functions only use representations of the values they are given?

Tags: arrays, c, function, implicit-conversion, pointer-arithmetic

i am new to learning C and i have a brief question: i have been told that functions always use representatives of the values passed to them, so it is not possible to change the values from within the function if you do not use a pointer.

We have frequently used functions to change arrays though?
Why can my function change an array if everything passed to the function is just a copy?

i am sorry if this is a stupid question but i did not find it answered anywhere.

Comment: Because an array passed to a function decays to a pointer to its first element.

Comment: When you pass an array to a function, you pass the address of that array in memory.

Comment: Since the array decays to a pointer (to its first element), it is the *pointers* value (i.e. where it is pointing) that is copied into the functions local argument variable.

Comment: Taking array decay as a given, I prefer to characterize the situation as such: you *can't* pass (bare) arrays to functions or receive them as function return values.  It's not even an error. C simply has no way to express such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

From the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
> operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, **an
> expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
> expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
> element of the array object** and is not an lvalue. If the array
> object has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

If you have a function like for example

```
void f( int a[], size_t n );
```

then the compiler adjusts the parameter having the array type to pointer to the array element type.

That is the above function declaration is equivalent to

```
void f( int *a, size_t n );
```

From the C Standar (6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes))d

> 7 **A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of type’’ shall be adjusted
> to ‘‘qualified pointer to type**’’, where the type qualifiers (if any)
> are those specified within the [ and ] of the array type derivation.
> If the keyword static also appears within the [ and ] of the array
> type derivation, then for each call to the function, the value of the
> corresponding actual argument shall provide access to the first
> element of an array with at least as many elements as specified by the
> size expression.

On the other hand, according to the first quote from the C Standard an array used as an argument expression is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element.

So the function deals with a pointer and using the pointer arithmetic and dereferencing obtained pointers can change elements of the passed array.

That is in fact elements of arrays are passed by reference indirectly through pointers to them.